# How to add files of specific extensions from current folder to path on Windows 10

Tags: cmd

I want to find all `*.py` files located in all subfolders and assign their full paths to `var` variable.

I have tried using:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir *.py /s/b') do set var=%var%;%~fa
```

But then `%var%` contains the last path of the command.

Comment: Unclear. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delayed expansion should have been used. In cmd, it is enabled with the `/V` option. You have to try:

```
cmd /V /k for /F "tokens=*" %A IN ('dir /s /b *.py') do if not defined var (set "var=%~fA") else (set "var=!var!;%~fA")
```

See about delayed expansion [here](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php).